# How to transfer values to function (e, dt, node, config) for dtOptions.buttons?

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable

I want to transfer values to  function (e, dt, node, config) for dtOptions.buttons

angular 6

How to transfer values to  function (e, dt, node, config) for dtOptions.buttons?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buttons-extension',
  templateUrl: 'buttons-extension.component.html'
})
export class ButtonsExtensionComponent implements OnInit {
  // Must be declared as "any", not as "DataTables.Settings"
  dtOptions: any = {};
  val=10;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      ajax: 'data/data.json',
      columns: [{
        title: 'ID',
        data: 'id'
      }, {
        title: 'First name',
        data: 'firstName'
      }, {
        title: 'Last name',
        data: 'lastName'
      }],
      // Declare the use of the extension in the dom parameter
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      // Configure the buttons
      buttons: [
        'columnsToggle',
        'colvis',
        'copy',
        'print',
        'excel',
        {
          text: 'Some button',
          key: '1',
          action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
            alert(this.val);
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

console.log: 
undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
{
  text: 'Some button',
  key: '1',
  action: (e, dt, node, config) => this.methodName(e, dt, node, config) {
  alert(this.val);
}
```

Comment: this do not work. core.js:1598 ERROR TypeError: _this.methodName is not a function

Comment: Also  
action: (e, dt, node, config) => this.methodNam; 


methodName(e, dt, node, config) {
  alert(this.val);
} not work

ERROR in src/app/form/tables/table/table.component.ts(65,20): error TS2339: Property 'Buttons' does not exist on type 'StaticFunctions'.